# AvalonDock layout groups like Visual Studio

Tags: avalondock

I'm new to Avalondock so excuse me if this is a pretty basic question. I want to achieve a layout that is similar to Visual Stuido with two layouts on the left side, the top window showing a kind of "project explorer", the bottom windows a property grid. Like that:[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghFLZ.png)

The windows should be visible, arranged and pinned per default.

Current XAML Looks like that:

```
<avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide >

        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup >
            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable ContentId="objects" Title="Project Objects" FloatingWidth="250">
                <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                </TreeView>
            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
         </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>

         <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable FloatingWidth="250" AutoHideWidth="250">
                <xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
         </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>

     </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
  </avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
```

That XAML producing a look like that: [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mck0u.png)

What should I change ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm realizing that I'm answering my own question. The easiest way is to either quickly code or download a sample application which has the ability to serialize the layout. I used this one on Codeplex: [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483507/AvalonDock-Tutorial-Part-Adding-a-Tool-Windo)

The output can then be used as new default in XAML.